# Django how to display foreign key in admin as list of links?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Say I have two Django models `Room` and `User`. I'll leave the models generic open here.

At `User` I have a one-to-many-relationship with `Room`, so that one Room may be used by many users but its usage is optional:

```
room = models.ForeignKey(Room, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='users')
```

**How do I show at `Room admin page` a section with all its users?**

I already tried `admin.TabularInline` and it shows all the user fields as editable, but I'd like to have a list of link to users (e.g. user name) with the possibility to add an existing user to the list.

I also tried adding the `related_name` users to the Room `ModelAdmin` `list_display` attribute, but nothing happend :D

Comment: You can extend the room admin form and add the users field to it. Another option would be to use explicit `through` model and use it to build inlines https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think still relevant. The following solution is compiled from the answers suggested in the related questions. Works quite well.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html, format_html_join
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import Room


def queryset_as_ul(qs, with_links=False, empty_value=''):
   """Takes in a queryset and renders it as a list (of links).
   """
   if with_links:
      meta = qs.model._meta
      view_name = f'admin:{meta.app_label}_{meta.model_name}_change'
      items = format_html_join(
         mark_safe('\n'),
         '<li><a href="{}">{}</a></li>',
         ((reverse(view_name, args=[r.pk]), r) for r in qs)
      )
   else:
      items = format_html_join(
         mark_safe('\n'),
         '<li>{}</li>',
         ((r,) for r in qs),
      )

   if items:
      return format_html('<ul>{}</ul>', items)
   else:
      return empty_value


class RoomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   # Adds the list of users beneath the room form.
   readonly_fields = ['roommates']

   @admin.display('Users')
   def roommates(self, instance):
      # Filter your queryset however you like.
      qs_users = instance.user_set.all()
      return queryset_as_ul(
         qs_users,
         with_links=True,
         empty_value=mark_safe('<span class="errors">None.</span>'),
      )

admin.site.register(Room, RoomAdmin)
```

(I found you also need some CSS to style the list because it doesn't line up quite so nicely by default. Left as an exercise for the reader.)